# Where to add NPM dependencies for running postinstall hooks?

Tags: json, node.js, npm, npm-install, post-install

So, I have a library `haste-mapper` ([link to Github](https://github.com/barbu110/haste-mapper/) - I would like some opinions on it). It uses `gulp`, `babel-core` and a few other npm packages to build itself so as to have valid JavaScript instead of Flow into the `build/` directory. I added that as a `postinstall` hook script in `package.json`:

```
"postinstall": "gulp build"
```

It works, the script starts running but it does not meet the required dependencies in the host package. I have `gulp` and `babel-core` as `devDependencies` and it seems not to install them. Adding them to `dependencies` seems semantically wrong. I tried adding them to `peerDependencies`, but instead of installing what's missing, it just complains about it.

How should I go about this?

P.S. [Here](https://github.com/barbu110/haste-mapper/blob/7d1325e2e2c9adac3dedb57d9462a48b80c7a0a7/package.json) is the `package.json`

Answer (score 5):

If you want to use something in a `postinstall` hook, it needs to be a `dependency`.

However, you're doing it wrong. You shouldn't be transpiling your code after the install. Instead, you should transpile  your code before you publish the package.

To do that, you will need to rename your script to `prepublish` so that it is run when you run `npm publish`. List gulp, babel, etc. as `devDependencies`. Add an `.npmignore` file in the root of your project, containing:

```
/src/
```

The `.npmignore` file works just like a `.gitignore`. You don't want your `src/` directory included in the published package, only `build/`. Make sure `.npmignore` is committed to git. If you don't have an `.npmignore`, npm will use the `.gitignore` file. This isn't what you want, since `build/` is ignored for version control, but should be included in the npm package.

When you run `npm publish`, `npm` will run your `prepublish` hook before bundling your package for the registry. Then when someone `npm install`s your package, they will get the `build/` folder, but not `src/`. Just what you want!

Comment: I always thought NPM grabs the code of the package straight from the git repository...

Comment: Nope, you push to npm separately.

Comment: "However, you're doing it wrong. ", What if the package is a private git repo.

Comment: @towry It's preferable to publish it as a private npm module. If you don't want to do that, you're basically forced to check your built code into git. You can either update the built code on every commit, or only for tagged releases.

Answer (score 3):

I started to leave a comment on RyanZim's answer because his technique is correct. However, I wanted to give a slightly different approach. Our company maintains a lot of open source projects and this is how we would advise you.

- Keep developing your project like you normally would. Your `.gitignore` file should be ignoring your dist directory (`/build` in your case).
- When you are ready to deploy, you want to build your code, bump your version number inside package.json, tag the changes, and push the built code to both github and npm.

The main idea is that we want to keep a copy of our built code in github along with a "tag" for that version. This allows us to see exactly what was pushed to npm for any particular version. The built code is not part of the master branch but exists **only** under a tag (which is sort of like a branch). When a user reports a bug and he's using version x.x.x, you can checkout that exact version and start debugging. When you fix the bug, you release a new "patch" and your user will get the changes the next time he runs `npm install` or `npm update`.

We have created a set of npm scripts to do most of this for us. Here is what we use (this goes in your package.json):

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "node build.js",
    "preversion": "npm run build",
    "version": "git commit -am \"Update dist for release\" && git checkout -b release && git add -f dist/",
    "postversion": "git push --tags && git checkout master && git branch -D release && git push",
    "release:pre": "npm version prerelease && npm publish",
    "release:patch": "npm version patch && npm publish",
    "release:minor": "npm version minor && npm publish",
    "release:major": "npm version major && npm publish"
}
```

I know that may look confusing so let me explain. Whenever we are ready to release new code, we run one of the `release:` commands. For example, when we run `npm run release:minor`, here is the list of commands which are run in order. I have annotated it so you can see what happens:

```
node build.js             ## run the build code - you will want to run gulp instead
npm version minor         ## bumps the version number in package.json and creates a new git tag
git commit -am "Update dist for release"    ## commit the package.json change to git (with new version number) - we will push it at the end
git checkout -b release   ## create a temporary "release" branch
git add -f dist/          ## force add our dist/ directory - you will want to add your build/ directory instead
npm publish               ## push the code to npm
git push --tags           ## push the built code and tags to github
git checkout master       ## go back to the master branch
git branch -D release     ## delete the temporary "release" branch
git push                  ## push the updated package.json to github
```

If you have any questions, please ask. You might want to do things in a slightly different order as your situation is a little different. Please feel free to ask questions. This code works really well on dozens of projects - we release new code multiple times a day.

Comment: Tip: let your CI do the releasing, that way the developer has to do less and when the developer has to do less, the developer makes less mistakes.

Comment: Ha, I didn't even want to touch CI as this post is overwhelming enough. Thanks though. Also, we do a lot of iterations and use CI only for running tests in multiple environments. When everything passes and we are ready, we release by hand which ensures that our tags are in sync with npm and nothing goes out too soon. We handle client projects differently. To each his own though.